# wordpress upload http error?

Tags: admin, uploads, memory

I'm trying to uplaod video files,my upload file size limit is 96mb,and I can upload videos until 10mb size,but I want to uplaod videos that have 20mb size.If I try to uplaod bigger video I get http error,I found on web a lot of solutions but none of them acctualy help me.Is there any other solution how to fix http uplaod error and uplaod bigger files on my wordpress site?
I have tried every thing from there links :

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/http-error-on-image-upload-still
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/flash-uploader-logs-out-during-crunching-phase
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/http-error-image-upload

Tnx in advance.

Anybody have idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Please include some details on what had you tried already, otherwise it is hard to come up with _other_ solutions.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: I've seen the same problem before and I think I remember seeing someone track down a number of places that WordPress hardcodes memory limits in core. I'll see if I can find the link (might have been another question on here).

Comment: If you read my answer below you might find that this is a host related issue and not a Wordpress issue at all. One way you can be sure is to write a simple file uploading PHP script and run it, then see if you get the same issues you're having in Wordpress. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: tnx,that will be great.

Comment: I've updated my answer below. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on shared hosting by any chance? Shared hosts tend to limit the max uploadable file size on their end and there is nothing you can add to your scripts to change that. If not, then I am mistaken and this is not the solution you are looking for.

However, if you are on shared hosting it might pay to contact them and ask them the max allowed file sizes they allow their shared hosting accounts to have. Some hosts however let you create a php.ini file, drop it into your site root directory set some hosting variables like upload limits, etc.

Try creating a file called 'php.ini' without the quotes and put in the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M  
post_max_size = 64M
```

Then place the php.ini file you just created into your Wordpress root directory.

A good way to see if it is your host or Wordpress installation is to create a simple file uploading test and then try uploading the same file. If you have the same issue, it isn't Wordpress and is your server configuration.

Create a page called "file.php" and then add in the following code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

Now create a file called "upload.php" and add in the following:

```
<?php

    $uploaddir = 'uploads';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo "<p>";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }

    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";

?>
```

Example code taken from here: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3729

Now see if that lets you upload a large file. If not, then we'll further try and debug your Wordpress installation to try and rectify the issue.

Comment: Hi,sorry for my late response,I have tried this and didn't help me.I just uploaded a file 25mb in folder

Comment: probably it is wp issue,for now,I will stop working on this,and use ftp for uploading files,than will later execute some sql command

Comment: So you're saying that the script let you upload a file without giving you any errors?

Comment: yes,I can upload without any problems,tnx for trying to help

Comment: Okay, so the obvious thing is that Wordpress is limiting uploads and it could be due to any of the above and below mentioned factors relating to limits. I'll look into a solution for you in a couple of hours and then post back what I find.

Comment: Quick question: if you look inside of your wp-admin folder do you see a php.ini file that has already been created for you?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the WordPress upload limit: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-size

Comment: I can set my uplaod file size,and I just setup it to 192mb,that didnt fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what error message you're getting in the server logs.

But, take a look at this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-size.

In your php.ini, add or edit the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 120MB
post_max_size = 120MB
```

Also you may need to add this to your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '120MB');
```

And also change your timeout values in your php.ini

```
max_execution_time
max_input_time
```

Set these to values that are larger than they are currently set to - and see what happens.

You should check these values are set correctly by checking the information returned by phpinfo()

This page seems to be a good source of all the PHP configuration settings for large file uploads: http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapUpload/wap_upload.asp?page=php2

Comment: I totaly forgot on wp_memory_limit,will try this,tnx

Comment: this didn't help

Comment: You're going to need to include more information: - what error are you getting in your apache logs. Where are you hosted - are you sure you have control over your own php.ini? Make a test php file and just put a call to phpinfo() into it, and see whether the changed values show up

Comment: I'm on ipage hosted,I have control over my php.ini,not sure how to get apache logs ? Can you guide me how to get apache logs?

Comment: check your host docs - server logs typically can be found at /var/logs/. Also, what does phpinfo() return? You might also need to edit php timeout values- I'm editing my answer with the necessary info.

Comment: max_execution time is 300 , and max input type is 60,memory limit is 36mb,not sure what to setup for these values.

Comment: and post_max_size is 192,and upload_max_size is 192mb

Comment: These values are in seconds, and set the maximum time that PHP will let a script execute (max_execution_time) and the maximum time PHP will wait for post data or a file upload. So, you'll need to work out the likely amount of time for a 100MB upload from a client (which could easily be an hour).

Comment: tnx for response,will try this.tnx

Comment: nope,this didn't help,I think that is not php issues,that wp bug.Realy don't know what to do.

Comment: This error also people get with images,think that size isn't problem,if you do not exced upload limit.

Comment: So, do ANY file uploads work? If not, are you sure you've checked folder permissions? Can you add an image to a post? What do your logs say?

Answer (score 0):

if all fails try adding this lines in your functions.php

```
function push_the_max(){
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '100M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '105M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
}
add_action('init','push_the_max');
```

Comment: it is the same thing,like changing php.ini,but I will try also this.

Comment: nope,it didn't help,maybe it is wordpress bug

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answers given to this question:

### [How to use more than 256MB of memory in the admin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3305/how-to-use-more-than-256mb-of-memory-in-the-admin)

Basically, there are some memory limits that are hard-coded, and one or two that are filterable. If you need to increase upload file size limits and memory limits, maybe some of those suggestions may help.

Comment: tnx will read post from link,and try to solve my problem.tnx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uploading from a different computer or internet connection?

I'm having a similar problem but have found that I can upload from one location when my client is unable to upload exactly the same file from a different location. [Upload media file problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7833/upload-media-file-problem)